# how to test constructorBinding annotation simply?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have some properties bean files with ConstructorBinding annotation.
However, it is difficult to do test except for adding the SpringBootTest annotation that takes much of the time.
here is the properties bean file.

```java
@Getter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sample.datasource")
public class SampleProperties {

    private final String url;
    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    @ConstructorBinding
    public SampleProperties(String url, String username, String password) {
        this.url = url;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I tried adding a class into the SpringBootTest classes field or ConfigurationContext annotation too but it printed the error below.
how can I do test those files simply?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 105 more
```

---

the test code is here.

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {DatasourcePropertiesConfiguration.class, SampleProperties.class})
class PropertiesConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    private DatasourcePropertiesConfiguration datasourcePropertiesConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    private SampleProperties sampleProperties;

    private static final String url = "localhost:3306";
    private static final String username = "root";
    private static final String password = "password123^";

    @Test
    void encoding() {
        String encodedUrl = datasourcePropertiesConfiguration.getUrl();
        String encodedUsername = datasourcePropertiesConfiguration.getUsername();
        String encodedPassword = datasourcePropertiesConfiguration.getPassword();

        assertThat(encodedUrl).isEqualTo(url);
        assertThat(encodedUsername).isEqualTo(username);
        assertThat(encodedPassword).isEqualTo(password);
    }
}
```

Comment: please add test class as well, you can inject required properties using @TestPropertySource then use it in test class.

Comment: @RaushanKumar thank you for text. I have been added the test code and I tried the annotation; is TestPropertySource, not working unfortunately